# im tring to recover my freinds contacts but when i go to gmail it will not let me put in his gmail account how do i do this

Tags: contacts

how do I recover my contacts from my freinds Google email account he lost his phone and when I go to gmail it won't except his email account only mine because it's my phone.

Comment: Welcome! Poor question. -1. Please [edit] your question and fix the spelling and grammar, then ping me using a comment beginning with "@unforgettableid:" afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask him to export his Google contacts as a .csv or .vcf file and send that file to you. Then import that file from the contacts app in your phone.